# Is IP address in US grouped by state?

Tags: networking, ip

I have our customers iso generated ip addresses where I like to do some analysis to see where our most customers are accessing our site.

I tried to do api calls to

```
http://ip-api.com/<ip address>
```

to retrieve the state where the ip address generated but there are over 4 million ip addresses to process and this will take some time.

Are ip addresses designated by State in the US? If first octets are designated to the states, I can then write a script to parse out the ip addresses. Other than api calls to determine the location of the ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using  something like Maxmind that can get the geo-location(city,State) of the IP addresses. They have an API that you can implement into your code to find the location of all IP's in a database.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did but I have over 4 million records to process. I was curious to see if first octets in ip addresses assigned by States or something like that?

Comment: They are all assigned by the internet service providers, and they necessarily do not assign by states.

Comment: @user37466026, ok. How is that these ip address search api's locate which states each ip address belongs to? As I said, I can do api calls, and did that but I have a very large amount of data to process. I was thinking if any indication in the ip address that these are belong to certain regions, that would make it very simple to analyze this type of data.